# Replace the null value with a suitable value

Tags: soap, wso2-esb

I have the folllowing soap response. Now I want to replace the null value with a suitable value. How can I achieve it?

```
       <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soapenvelope">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                    <Entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                       <Entry>
                             <empId>xxx</empId>
                             <empName>yyy</empName>
                             <allocatedDesk>null</allocatedDesk>
                       </Entry>
                    </Entries>
                   </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: It seems like very few people are viewing this question. Which is the technology that you use for creating/consuming the service? WCF/Java or something like that? Add tag for that technology also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XSLT to replace the "null":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath-default-namespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/soapenv:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="allocatedDesk[text()='null']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="'YOUR DESIRED TEXT'"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|node()|@*">
        <!-- copy all elements -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xslt mediator is being used to apply the XSLT on your MessageContext in WSO2. See the documentation:
http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/mediators/xslt.html